# Permanent migration from UK to Belgium/Europe

Tags: united-kingdom, europe

Due to certain family problems, we are planning to move from the UK to Belgium OR any other European country. Everyone in my family has UK citizenship and a passport. What's the process of moving permanently from the UK to Europe? Do we have to give up our UK passport in order to get European passports?

Comment: What does "cylinder" mean in this context?  You won't get a European passport until you've lived in Europe for some years.  Oh, and Europe is still not a country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After five years of uninterrupted living in Belgium, citizens from the European Union (EU), the European Economic Area (EEA – EU plus Iceland, Liechtenstein and Norway) and Switzerland acquire permanent residence automatically.

Non-EU/EEA/Swiss citizens are also eligible after five years but must submit an application with their local municipality for permanent residence. If you hold a Blue Card from another EU-member state, and have lived elsewhere in the EU, this can count towards your five-year period.

An 'uninterrupted' period is defined as that you have resided legally and continuously in Belgium during the five years preceding your application, without having left the Belgian territory for a continuous period of more than six months.

In addition, you cannot have been absent from Belgium more than one year in total, meanng the combination of all your trips abroad cannot exceed one year in the five-year period.

After five to 10 years, both EU and non-EU residents in Belgium can apply for Belgian nationality, although a strict set of conditions must be met.

Complete Migration Procedure Defined by UK GOV can be found at:

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/living-in-belgium

Comment: How Brexit impact on it?

Comment: @Nestsouls Unknown.

Comment: @Nestsouls: Negotiations between UK and EU are at a standstill because they can't agree about divorce payments, about the UK / Ireland border, and what you are asking: Rights of EU citizens in the UK and rights of British citizens in the EU.